# Malformed Input Error in setEndpointAttributes in AWS SNS ios sdk 1.6.1

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using the iOS SDK to set endpoint attributes for an endPoint Arn with the following code-

```
SNSSetEndpointAttributesRequest *req = [[SNSSetEndpointAttributesRequest alloc] init];
req.endpointArn = arn;
[req setAttributesValue:@"true" forKey:@"Enabled"];
@try {
    [[self sharedClient] setEndpointAttributes:req];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception is: %@", exception.description);
}
```

I have verified that the endpoint Arn is valid. However, there seems to be some issue with the format of the attributes and I am not able to figure out the best way to do this. Executing the above code gives the error:

`Exception is: AmazonServiceException { RequestId:<reqid>, ErrorCode:MalformedInput, Message:Top level element may not be treated as a list }`

Any idea what the proper format would be?
The documentation doesn't seems to be a great help either.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/SNSSetEndpointAttributesRequest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, this is indeed a bug in the AWS SDK for iOS.  We've addressed in the source on our GitHub repository:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/commit/de19c0d343b34f4fa2819d99db7f425a58cca422

You'll unfortunately need to rebuild the framework in order to pick up this fix.  While it only covers the combined framework, you might find [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3FHW3DMZ7MTJZ/Building-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-from-Source) useful in rebuilding the AWSSNS.framework file.

Comment: Thank you Bob. How long will it take until the release of 1.6.2

Comment: @JohnPayne Unfortunately I can't commit to a timeline for the next release other than to say that we are hoping to release it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug that AWS is working on

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=134622#